# Install private python package in Gitlab CI using CI token

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

From my Gitlab CI I'm trying to install a Python package from a private registry with this line:

```
pip install pipelinewriter --index-url https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/pypi/simple
```

This fails: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement`.

When I use my PAT, it succeeds:

```
pip install pipelinewriter --index-url https://__token__:<MY_PAT>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/pypi/simple
```

Preferably I'd use the CI token instead of my PAT. Is this possible?

I was able to push the package using the CI token, following [these instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/index.html#using-requirementstxt). This makes me think it should be possible to install the package using the same credentials.

I also tried adding some lines to the `.netrc` file [as suggested by others](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/294130):

```
.install_python_dependencies:
  before_script:
    - echo "Hacky credentials..."
    - echo "machine gitlab.com" > ~/.netrc
    - echo "login gitlab-ci-token" >> ~/.netrc
    - echo "password ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" >> ~/.netrc

    - echo "Installing Python dependencies..."
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pip install pipelinewriter --index-url https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/pypi/simple
    # - pip install pipelinewriter --index-url https://__token__:${PAT}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/pypi/simple >>> This works
    - export PYTHONPATH="."
```

But I keep facing the some error.

Comment: Is the Python registry in the same GitLab project as the CI pipeline?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same project.

Comment: Seems like the process for installing a package is not well documented, the solution can be found here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/294130

Comment: I found that issue before but didn't solve my problem. I've incorporated it in my question.

Comment: @bhito They're not in the same project. My bad. I was confused with the Gitlab terminology.

Comment: Ah okay that makes it a totally different issue, have added an answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the pipeline trying to pull the package from the registry it's in another project, then the issue lies in the permissions that `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` has.

The project that attempts to pull from the pipeline needs to be allowlisted to have cross-project permissions. That option is located at `Settings > CI/CD` menu.

More details can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.co.jp/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#configure-the-job-token-scope-limit)

Comment: I added the project containing the package but still no luck